# How to display data in tabular format in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android. Now I am working on some database sample programs.
Now I have a problem in displaying the data retrieved from database in
a tabular format. If anyone know the answer, please help me with the
source code.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `TableLayout` wrapped in a `ScrollView`. Or you can use a `GridView`. It depends on whether or not you want to allow people to select cells or not.